# How can I add a custom onclick-handler to my SPAN-tags - like the Skype addon does?

Tags: internet-explorer, html

When I look at the source code for a webpage that has been rendered by Skype's Internet Explorer add on, I find that their custom html-element is a SPAN element with a specific attribute, "skypeaction" that is set to "dropdown" - this is, I suppose, to be able to open a dropdown menu when the user clicks on that element.

Apart from this, there is no javascript or anything that I can see that actually makes the dropdown menu pop up. I do know that the CSS code for the popup is an embedded reference in the skypeplugin dll, but I do not understand how this element is clickable!

Does someone here know how this might work, and if it's possible for me to replicate this in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype installs a BHO and a helper extension of some sort that does the handling of the click in native code.  Probably by doing something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508(VS.85).aspx).

If you go to Tools -> Manage Add-ons in IE you can see they have a BHO and another helper extension that are registered.

[image: Skype manage add-ons screen shot.]